# How to allow for download of file from Firebase storage bucket in swift

Tags: swift, firebase-storage

So I have a backend that uploads a PKPass file to my storage bucket.  I'm trying to download it in Swift.

Download Function

```
 func downloadPass(completion: @escaping((Bool) -> () )) {
        self.storageRef.child("passes/custom.pkpass").getData(maxSize: Int64(1 * 1024 * 1024)) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let pass = try PKPass(data: data)
                    self.newPass = pass
                    completion(true)
                } catch let passError {
                    print("Error creating PKPass: \(passError)")
                    completion(false) // Updated this to return false on error instead of nil, as your completion handler expects a Bool.
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error downloading resource: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get....

> "Error downloading resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FirebaseStorage.StorageError error 4.)"

I'm just trying to figure out, do I need a googleservice-info file or is there something in my settings I need to set up to allow for the download...or something else?

Comment: You shouldn't use `localizedDescription` -- it has much less information than just printing the error. And, yes, you'll need a `googleservice-info` file. Check the Firebase Storage documentation for information on how to set up your project.